# Create OS X Today Extension without containing app

Tags: macos, today-extension

On the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1) website it states:

> To deliver an OS X app extension, it’s recommended that you submit
>   your containing app to the App Store, but it’s not required.

However, to make a Today Extension from what I understand: I must create a Cocoa OS X application then add a "Today Extension" as a target. However, I do not want/need this main containing app. All I need is the extension.

So, **how do I create an extension without a containing app?** Even though technically I need to develop the containing app to create an extension target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misreading this: what they are saying is that an OS X app extension may be distributed OUTSIDE the app store - if you continue reading, you will see the following:

> If you distribute an OS X app extension outside of the Mac App Store, Gatekeeper prevents the extension from running until the user opens and approves the containing app. Further, if you code sign with a certificate other than your Developer ID, users must explicitly override Gatekeeper to open the containing app to make your extension available.

All extensions, at this writing, **must be part of a container app** and Apple devotes a large number of pages describing how, why, etc. My understanding (and work on extensions) is that all extensions must be part of a containing application. If there is a way to do so without the container app, Apple has not indicated it.

Comment: You're completely correct, rereading it it makes more sense now. Thank you!!

Comment: Not sure if it is right. There is a extension on the app store without a containing app: This Month